# Limit of a converging series

Tags: limits, analysis

I want to calculate
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^3-1}{x_n-1}$$
whereas $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1.$$ and $x_n≠1$

My idea:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^3-1}{x_n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(x_n^2+x_n+1)(x_n-1)}{x_n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^2+x_n+1=1^2+1+1=3$$

Does this make any sense? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct but you should add facts like $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+x_n+x_n^2) = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n^2+\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n+\lim_{n \to \infty}1 = (\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n) \cdot(\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} 1
$$

and as $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = 1$ the limit is 3

Comment: as the limit may not exist

Comment: Ok thank you for the hints! I will add them to my solution